# DIV elements not touching

Tags: css, image, html

I'm fairly new to CSS and I need help with an issue concerning CSS and DIVS. I have some .JPG slices within a div tag and I need them to seamlessly fit so that it looks like one whole document. Please take a look.

Sample link: (http://goo.gl/nmFDFB)

#### HTML

```
<section class="section_01">
  <p class="section"><img src="images/lp_01.jpg" name="lp01" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" id="lp_01"></p>
</section>

<section class="section_02">
  <p class="section"><img src="images/lp_02.jpg" name="lp02" border="0" id="lp_02"></p>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
html {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 100%;
    ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    min-width: 990px;
}
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
/* base */

a {
    color: #31b7fa;
}
a:hover { /* add default link :hover class here */
}
div {
    top: 0px;
    clip: rect(0px,auto,auto,auto);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
/* Sticky Navigation */
#sticky_navigation {
    z-index:600;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:url(../images/sticky.png) no-repeat top center;
    min-width:960px;
    height:105px;
    width:100%
}
#sticky_navigation a {
    display:block;
    height:105px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: You are not using any **div** elements _at all_ in the either the HTML or linked sample you provided! You are using sections and paragraphs, the latter of which come with a margin. If that is your code, that's your problem, and as a deeper problem you appear to be misunderstanding something about what's going on here. If that is not your code, what _is_ your code and what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the images in `p` tags; it's unnecessary, and `p` tags generally have margins, which is causing your problem.

Another solution is to put this in your css:

```
p { margin: 0 }
```

That will get rid of the margins. But like I said, I do not recommend it. It would be better to remove the `p` tags.

Also, browsers have web development tools that you can use that will show you what is causing problems like this. For example, if you are using Chrome, `ctrl+shift+j` will open the development window.